# How to access a .Net web service from a Delphi Win32 application?

Tags: .net, web-services, delphi, winapi, com

What options do I have if I want to enable a Delphi Win32 application to consume a .Net webservice?

Is it possible to interact directly? Or do I have to resort to a middleman-software communicating to the Delphi application per COM for instance?

The Delphi application in question is written in Delphi 2006 but is planned to be updated to Delphi XE soon.

Comment: Good news! You access it the same way you access any other Web service. You access it through *the Web*, just like you access Web *sites*. If you can't talk to the service via plain old wget, then it's not actually a Web service in the first place. .Net is completely irrelevant.

Comment: This could certainly be an option for simple web services. But how feasible is this in a more complex real world application? As I see it this would require an additional layer of interpretation and with this complexity where the direct access of an interface and executing its methods is much more transparent to the developers.

Comment: Were you addressing my comment, Amenti? Yes, go ahead build your application atop as many layers as you want. My point is that beneath it all is still just the Web, nothing special. The Web separates your client application from the server application. No matter how many layers you build on top of it, the Web is still the barrier. Whatever's on the server side of that barrier is irrelevant to everything you do on the client side. The server could be .Net, Linux, or even a toaster, and it would make no difference to your client program.

Comment: @RobKennedy A toaster **could** make a difference. It could make breakfast. `[HTTPGet][HTTPBreakfast]foo()`...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While your project is open in Delphi IDE, go to:

**File | New | Other... | Delphi Projects | WebServices | WSDL Importer**

Now WSDL importer wizard will start. Type in WSDL address for your webservice, and press Next. It will show you different options about how to process the WSDL. You can change the options if needed. Eventually, when the wizard is finished, you will have a new unit in your project which contains  client-side wrapper classes and interfaces for your webservice. Now you can use this class in different ways. 
The simplest method is to call a function which is named Get(Your_WebService_Name). For example if your webservice name is TestWebService, the function will be named GetTestWebService.

The function will return an interface which represents the same interface as your webservice, now you can call the methods of this interface, and it will automatically transfer the request to the remote server, and return the result back to you. An example source code could look like this:

```
var
  MyTestService: ITestService;
begin
  MyTestService := GetTestService();
  MyTestService.TestMethod;
end;
```

Another option is that you setup a THttpRio object manually, and use it. Actually that is what that Get(Your_WebService_Name) function does internally.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the line `InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(xxx), ioDocument);` to your initialize section of the generated imported file. It will work as a charm.
NOTE: xxx must be replaced with your imported web service class name.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't work with C# web service, period. Delphi client doesn't understand the header of C# and vice versa.

Comment: actually there are no "C# web services" - .Net WCF uses for example SOAP messages, which are just XML

Comment: how does the 'header of C#' look like?